How to work with todo quick action on gitlab Merge Requests?
We use a self-hosted gitlab@17.5.3
I, as a developer, have opened a Merged Request. Some other developer added a comment. I reply to the comment only with a quick action:
/todo do a thing

Thereby no actual comment is added on the page. A popup appears on the page that my todo was added:

yet on the web interface I don't see anything.
I was expecting a list, at best with a checkbox, for me to then be able to toggle my todo as done.
I found on the left sidebar a todo button:

which opens an overview (I pinked out the branch name):

Yet this overview is not helpful, as it just states "You added a to-do item", yet provides no context. Clicking the link opens the Merge Request page, providing no context on the actual to-do.
I can toggle the todo as done here, yet without anything to go by, this is not a decent workflow.
Am I using this feature correctly? What is the intended workflow with gitlab's todo?
How, if I even can, can I achieve a list of todos that I can toggle on the Merge Request view?
Note: I don't want to use the "unresolved threads" and "resolve thread" feature for this use-case. In our own gitlab worflow marking a thread as resolved is the responsibility of the reviewer; we may even keep them unresolved intentionally.
I as a developer want to generate a list of todos, at best via comments, and I want to see their actual content.
I would expect a list on the Merge Request page in the form of:
[ ] do a thing
[ ] do another thing
[X] do yet another thing

